# comparing two files and priniting lines with similar strings in one file

Tags: bash, text, compression

I have two file which I need to compare, and if the first column in file1 matches part of the fisrt columns in file2, then add them side by side in file3, below is an example:

File1:

```
123123,ABC,2016-08-18,18:53:53
456456,ABC,2016-08-18,18:53:53
789789,ABC,2016-08-18,18:53:53
123123,ABC,2016-02-15,12:46:22
```

File2

```
789789_TTT,567774,223452
123123_TTT,121212,343434
456456_TTT,323232,223344
```

output:

```
123123,ABC,2016-08-18,18:53:53,123123_TTT,121212,343434
456456,ABC,2016-08-18,18:53:53,456456_TTT,323232,223344
789789,ABC,2016-08-18,18:53:53,789789_TTT,567774,223452
123123,ABC,2016-02-15,18:53:53,123123_TTT,121212,343434
```

Thanks..

Comment: is the last line of output supposed to be `123123,ABC,2016-02-15,12:46:22,123123_TTT,121212,343434`

Comment: yes, since column 1 in file 1 is matching the first col in file 2

Answer (score 1):

Usin Gnu AWK:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[gensub(/([^_]*)_.*/,"\\1","g",$1)]=$0;next} $1 in a{print $0","a[$1]}' file2 file1
123123,ABC,2016-08-18,18:53:53 123123_TTT,121212,343434
456456,ABC,2016-08-18,18:53:53 456456_TTT,323232,223344
789789,ABC,2016-08-18,18:53:53 789789_TTT,567774,223452
123123,ABC,2016-02-15,12:46:22 123123_TTT,121212,343434
```

Explanation:

```
NR==FNR {                                   # for the first file (file2)
    a[gensub(/([^_]*)_.*/,"\\1","g",$1)]=$0 # store to array
    next
} 
$1 in a {                                   # if the key from second file in array
    print $0","a[$1]                        # output
}
```

Comment: thanks, but im getting an error when using it: `awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[gensub(/([^_]*)_.*/,"\\1","g",$1)]=$0;next} $1 in a{print $0","a[$1]}' file2.txt file1.txt
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1`

Comment: That's odd. It works fine on my computer. Are you using Gnu awk?

Answer (score 1):

awk solution matches keys formed from file2 against column 1 of file1 - should also work on Solaris using /usr/xpg4/bin/awk - I took the liberty of assuming the last line of OP output has a typo

```
file1=$1
file2=$2
AWK=awk
[[ $(uname) == SunOS ]] && AWK=/usr/xpg4/bin/awk
$AWK -F',' '
BEGIN{OFS=","}
# file2 key is part of $1 till underscore 
FNR==NR{key=substr($1,1,index($1,"_")-1); f2[key]=$0; next}
$1 in f2 {print $0, f2[$1]}
' $file2 $file1
```

tested

```
123123,ABC,2016-08-18,18:53:53,123123_TTT,121212,343434
456456,ABC,2016-08-18,18:53:53,456456_TTT,323232,223344
789789,ABC,2016-08-18,18:53:53,789789_TTT,567774,223452
123123,ABC,2016-02-15,12:46:22,123123_TTT,121212,343434
```

Comment: thanks, but im getting and error when using it:

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: `-bash-3.2# file1=$1
-bash-3.2# file2=$2
-bash-3.2# awk -F',' '
> BEGIN{OFS=","}
> # file2 key is part of $1 till underscore 
> ARGIND==1{key=substr($1,1,index($1,"_")-1); f2[key]=$0; next}
> $1 in f2 {print $0, f2[$1]}
> ' $file2 $file1
awk: syntax error near line 5
awk: bailing out near line 5`

Comment: are you using gnu awk? what does `awk -V` say?

Comment: I recommend putting the code in a file then running it with the two filename arguments

Comment: nothing, its blank, `-bash-3.2# awk -V 
`

Comment: what OS is it? Not Linux?

Comment: im using a solaris platform -bash-3.2# uname -a
SunOS AAA 5.10 Generic_148888-01 sun4v sparc SUNW,Netra-T2000

Comment: try my pure bash solution just posted

Comment: also modified this awk solution to work with Solaris XPG4 awk

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash solution

```
file1=$1
file2=$2
while IFS= read -r line; do
  key=${line%%_*}
  f2[key]=$line
done <$file2
while IFS= read -r line; do
  key=${line%%,*}
  [[ -n ${f2[key]} ]] || continue
  echo "$line,${f2[key]}"
done <$file1
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!!